# How can I migrate an existing Wordpress application to Amazon EC2 instane

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an application that is designed in `PHP, Wordpress, MySQL`. This application is residing on one server.

Now I want to migrate the application on an `Amazon EC2 instance`.

How can I do that? Also I would like to tell you that I have not developed the application. I do not have any experience in PHP wordpress.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux os??

Comment: the application is residing on Linux Centos instance and it will be migrated to lnux centos instance.

Comment: Please go through this step by step article and let us know if you face any difficulty in any of the steps - http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/

Comment: This link provide the steps to configure Lamp Stack on EC2. I have configured lamp Stack but don't know how to migrate the application.

Comment: What is stopping you from just deploying the code..There are tons of walk throughs for this..install apache & php, open the ports in the firewall from the EC2 security group, deploy your code, and you should be able to get your site up and running...we can help you if you are stuck in something..

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html - This will give you some insight on the hosting part..

Comment: I am facing an issue, I installed wordpress in html folder and the site folder also in html. the site is not working because of some issues. also the wordpress default page is not working